# I am not able to update or drop these two tables in my database because of this error:

Tags: mysql, database

Error Code: 3730. Cannot drop table 'liga' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'verein_ibfk_1' on table 'verein'

I'm even not able to insert any data in on of these tables because then the error: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bundesliga`.`verein`, CONSTRAINT `verein_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Liga`) REFERENCES `liga` (`Liga_Nr`)).

In the table 'verein', 'V_ID' is the primary key.
In the table 'liga', 'Liga_Nr' is the primary key.
The foreign key 'Liga' of the table 'verein' goes straight to the primary key 'Liga_Nr' of the table 'liga'.
The foreign key 'Meister' of the table 'liga' goes straight to the primary key 'V_ID' of the table 'verein'.
(as you can see in the png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWkRz.png)

describe table 'verein':

| Flied | Type | NULL | Key |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V_ID | int | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| Name | varchar(100) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Plazierung | int | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Liga | int | YES | MUL | NULL |  |

describe table 'liga':

| Flied | Type | NULL | Key |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Liga_Nr | int | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| Verband | varchar(50) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Erstaustragung | date | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Meister | int | YES | MUL | NULL |  |
| Rekordspieler | varchar(50) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Spiele_Rekordspieler | int | YES |  | NULL |  |

So my tables are connected as parent to child ('V_ID' to 'Meister') but also as child to parent ('Liga_Nr' to 'Liga'). So how could I solve the problem?

Thank you for your answers

@P.Salmon I think you mean these code?:

show create table 'verein':

```sql
CREATE TABLE `verein` (
  `V_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Plazierung` int(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Liga` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`V_ID`),
  KEY `Liga` (`Liga`),
  CONSTRAINT `verein_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Liga`) REFERENCES `liga` (`Liga_Nr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

show create table liga:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `liga` (
  `Liga_Nr` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Verband` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Erstaustragung` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Meister` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rekordspieler` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Spiele_Rekordspieler` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Liga_Nr`),
  KEY `Meister` (`Meister`),
  CONSTRAINT `liga_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Meister`) REFERENCES `verein` (`V_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Sry for my formatation, its my first question and I don't know how to format it right.

Comment: To avoid excess verbiage please add the output from SHOW CREATE TABLE <table> for all the tables as text to the question.

Comment: You shouldn't have a circular FK reference. I would remove Liga from the verein table.

Comment: ALTER TABLE x DROP FOREIGN KEY x; before drop table

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what you are trying to do with the circular references but I suggest you start by [dropping both the constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#:%7E:text=the%20foreign%20key.-,Dropping%20Foreign%20Key%20Constraints) -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `verein`
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `verein_ibfk_1`;

ALTER TABLE `liga`
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `liga_ibfk_1`;
```

You have some very strange column types - `int(40)`, `int(1)` & `int(255)`

Some light reading -

- [11.1.1 Numeric Data Type Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html)
- [11.1.2 Integer Types (Exact Value)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)
- [11.1.6 Numeric Type Attributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)
- [11.8 Choosing the Right Type for a Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/choosing-types.html)